# Print at a specific location in java output stream

Tags: java

```
 String s1= "SAM";
 int x=30;
 System.out.printf(s1); // prints at left most 
 s1=String.format("%03d",x);// formatting a number by 3 digits 
 System.out.printf("%15s",s1);//padding by 15 digits 
 System.out.println();
```

the task is to print the string and number in correct padding
i.e whatever the length of string the number should start at 16th position.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to *javadoc* for [format string syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

In order for the string to be left justified, you need to use `%-15s`. And if `s1` is longer than 15 charatcters, you need to shorten it.

```java
String s1 = "antidisestablishmentarianism";
int len = s1.length();
if (len > 15) {
    s1 = s1.substring(0, 15);
}
System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1, len);
```

Running the above code prints the following.

```
antidisestablis028
```

And using the example in your question.

```
String s1 = "SAM";
int len = s1.length();
if (len > 15) {
    s1 = s1.substring(0, 15);
}
int x = 30;
System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x);
```

Output is

```
SAM            030
```

Comment: Thanks a Lott,  this helps in my learning process about formatting !!

Comment: @Pavankumar you're welcome. Remember, _javadoc_ is your friend. And for learning Java I recommend [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: i am just starting java i ll follow  ur recommendation ! <3

Answer (score 0):

Your example is already padded by 13 spaces, so the number is at 16th position. So I thought you might want to padded by 15 in between of them. So the easiest is to use an empty string like following:

```java
String s = "SAM";
int x = 30;
        
System.out.printf(s); //Prints at the most left
s = String.format("%03d", x); //Format the number by 3 digits 
System.out.printf("%15s%s", "", s); //Padded by 15 digits 
System.out.println();
```

```
SAM               030
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following template to achieve the result

```
    String Wrd = "SPKJ";
    int intVAlFor = 35;
    String Vn = "";
    
    if(Wrd.length()<= 15){
        Vn =  String.format("%0"+ (15 - Wrd.length() )+"d%s",0 ,Wrd);
        Vn = Vn + Integer.toString(intVAlFor);
    } else {
        Vn = Wrd.substring(0, 15);
        Vn = Vn + Integer.toString(intVAlFor);
    }
    
    System.out.println(Vn);
```

Output :

```
00000000000SPKJ35
```

You can change the formatting respective to formatting you want to use (Right Padding / Left Padding by making changes in `String.format()`)